# how to set default coding to set for all external links at website should open in new tab using in cakephp coding

Tags: php, cakephp

HI on our website we have allowed user on their profile to publish other website links to described more about their work ,expertise etc.

So what I want to set a default code by which whatever external link is published in any section(ex. their answers,profile) at my website should be open in new tab. My website is running using cakephp code.

Thanks for help...

Answer (score 0):

```
var comp = new RegExp(location.host);

$('a').each(function(){
   if(!comp.test($(this).attr('href'))){
     $(this).attr('target','_blank');
   }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aus7ku39/)

Comment: Thanks @dinesh for reply but I am not searching for this solution my problem like I know where we are using links we have setted to open in a new tab but accidently user put links in mid-way of his/her profile summary so in that case that link open in same tab so I want to avoid this situation because we can't check all user summary & fix that

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 1.3 set the `target` option in the option array to `_blank` when using the HtmlHelper:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('my Website', 'http://my.web.site/', array('target' => '_blank')); ?>
```

[Doku](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/HTML.html#link)

CakePHP 2.x seems to work the same way. But i have not tested it.

Comment: No@Richard not this thing like I know where we are using links we have setted to open in a new tab but accidently user put links in mid-way of his/her profile summary so in that case that link open in same tab so I want to avoid this situation because we can't check all user summary & fix that